# use script JavaScript in contoller laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, controller

i need to use this script inside a laravel controller. the script uses a facial recognition library to compare the faces that are in the photos. How can I use this code inside a public function?

```
    const imageUpload = document.getElementById('imageUpload')
Promise.all([
    faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models')
  ]).then(start)

 
  
  

async function start() {
  
  document.body.append('Loaded')
  imageUpload.addEventListener('change', async () => {
    
    image = await faceapi.bufferToImage(imageUpload.files[0])
    
    const descriptions = []
    const detections1 = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(image).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceDescriptors();
    
    const faceMatcher = new faceapi.FaceMatcher(detections1, 0.6)

    var a = 0;
    const images = [];
    for (var i = 100; i <= 618; i++) {
      let image = 0;
      let img = new Image();
      img.src = 'test/' + i + '.jpeg';
      image = i + '.jpeg';
  
      const results = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(img).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceDescriptors()
      results.forEach(fd => {
        const bestMatch = faceMatcher.findBestMatch(fd.descriptor)

        if (bestMatch.label == "person 1") {
          
          images[a] = image;
          a++;
        }
        
      })
    
     
      }
  })
  

  
  }
```

This project is to work as an API, I don't want it to have views, the user will just have an APP in react native making requests to the laravel API

Comment: You could spin up some kind of selenium hack server side browser, bla bla bla... but let me save you a few weeks - you need to run that code client side.

Comment: @TarekAdam the suggestion is to run this code in react native?

Comment: Hi @pedro, basically yes.  Client side you have a javascript engine.  Server-side-php, you typically would not have the ability to execute js - unless you did some hacky selenium headless chrome or something.

Comment: Or - you could create a server side node.js micro-service

Comment: I guess my point is - the php interpreter does not execute javascript.  Typically, it just sends js to the client as code.  For server side js execution you can use node.

Comment: @TarekAdam how do i use headless browser for blade views? I already found it but it works for www.examplesite.com

Comment: Hi @pedro, It's just a web browser.  "headless" means theres no monitor attached.  So you can point at a url where the js is hosted.  You can test your host with a regular browser.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel is php.  The php interpreter does not ***execute*** javascript.  You can run JS in a browser OR in a nodeJS micro-service.  If you really want to get funky you can setup a headless browser on your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run javascript in Laravel controller. Also this function loads from the DOM, so it needs a document.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).